# Is it possible to serialize JSON with @attributes into a C# class

Tags: c#, json

Given a simple snippet of JSON

```
{
    "@attributes" : { 
         "version" : "1.0"
     },
     "item:" : {
         "@attributes" : {
             "name" : "foo",
             "id" : "bar"
          }
     }
}
```

Is it possible to serialize this into a C# class?  Using json2charp.com generates funky invalid class definitions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, provided you have a class definition in place which looks exactly like this json object.

```
`class ABC{  
      Attribute attirbute;
      Item item;
}`
```

But you'll have to either the change the way in which you write your json or make additional classes.
Wat i mean is '@attribute' over here points another key-vlaue pair and not a single value.
So, you should have a class which takes version as a member in this case i am writting it as `Attribute` and than you'll have to put that class a member of the `class ABC`.

Comment: Ok, so basically the goop that json2csharp has it right and I have to define a class for every @attribute value.  Meh. Thanks.

Comment: Yes indeed, because json is nothing but a object and object uses nothing but a class as a template. So, going from json to a c# object you should have some structural similarity.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, you might find it useful - I know I have [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)